# 3 Table triangle Pattern

Tags: c

Please help me to write C code to get this pattern:

```
3
6 9 
12 15 18
21 24 27 30
```

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i,j,r=0,k=1;
    for(i=1; i<=4; i++)
    {
        while(k!=11)
        {
            r=3*k;
            k=k+1;

            for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
            {
                printf("%d ",r);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it. May be help you : https://wandbox.org/permlink/1i6d0YDP9i2q62mG

Comment: `puts("3\n6 9\n12 15 18\n21 24 27 30");`

Answer (score 0):

This what you need:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int rows, i, j, number= 3;                
    for (i=1; i<=4; i++) 
    {
        for (j=1; j<=i; ++j)
        { 
            printf("%d ", number);
            number+=3;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Just take a number equals to 3 and for each j add 3 to number

Answer (score 0):

One loop, 3 variables (`l`, `ll`, and `i`.  `n` specifies the size of the triangle)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const int n = 10;
    int l = 1;
    int ll = 1;
    
    for(int i=1; i<=n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d %s", 3*i, --l? "" : (l=++ll,"\n"));
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Link to IDEOne](https://ideone.com/MtBTIY)

### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4212KB
3 
6 9 
12 15 18 
21 24 27 30
```